# Algorithm for shared complex edge simplification

Tags: compression

I have been looking for an algorithm that evaluates a shared complex edge between two objects to determine which of the two is 'facing inwards', which can then be simplified by converting the edge in a straight line. In my situation the adjusted object will be painted beneath the unmodified object, and thus will have no visual effect.

The image below illustrates what I want to achieve.

[image: example]

Is anyone aware of an algorithm that does this?

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but that looks very much like a patent diagram in which case, doesn't it explain how it's done?

Comment: @SimonF you are correct! Unfortunately, it does not go into detail as to how it should be achieved.

Comment: Hmm. Given a patent is supposed to be implementable by an "average skilled" person in the field, that doesn't sound promising.   Having said that, it looks as though the right edge of each piece is part of the convex hull. There are documented algorithms for finding that, if that's of use to you.